# How to add new line items in a APS.net webform and submit to database

Tags: asp.net, input, dynamic, webforms, controls

Please note: I do not necessarily need working code. I just don't know how to word what I am looking for to even find an answer on the web. I guess i'm just asking for a little guidance on what kind of control I would to use to accomplish my goal.

Basically when I go to a job site I will use different amounts and types of inventory. So one line item would consist of

1. Item Description
2. Quantity Used
3. UsedByTech

I'm collecting these via webform text box. I would like to have a button that says "Add" and then allows me to input another line item, and so on.

Then at some point a submit button on the form would gather those line items and input them in to a MSSQL databse.

I'm currently using ASP.Net framwork and webforms.

Can somone please tell me what kind of control would allow this a may be give me some hints about what to search for?

Comment: "dynamic" covers it... so your view becomes a dynamic view that can add/remove items.  So think arrays of view-type items, tied to arrays of data.  I would ditch webforms.  There's better options now.  (Not that you couldn't do this in webforms if you wanted, but they're legacy now...)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is actually quite easy - but we let asp.net do most of the work for us.

So, we assume we have these two tables:

[image]

so, we have a table to list out the Job Sites

And then as per above, we have a table to list out the Job items for each site.

Ok, so we display the Job Sites.

Drop in a Gridview - build it using the wizards:

[image]

Now, blow out (delete) the data source from the page - don't need it.
Remove the DataSource setting for the Gridview

And lets drop in a plane jane button into that grid.

Thus, this markup - most of it was generated for me

```
   <div style="padding:25px">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="40%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="JobSite" HeaderText="JobSite" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="JobDate" HeaderText="JobDate" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Foreman" HeaderText="Foreman" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View Job" CssClass="btn"
                            Onclick="cmdView_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
```

And our code to load this grid is thus this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GridView1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * from JobSites Order by JobDate")
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Ok, we now have this:

[image]

Ok, so now we need to wire up that "view" button.

So, we grab the PK row value - jump to our edit items page;

```
Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.Parent.Parent

    ' get PK database ID
    Dim PK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    ' Now jump to our job add job items page

    Session("JobID") = PK
    Response.Redirect("JobAddItems.aspx")

End Sub
```

So, now we need to build our 2nd page.

I could use a repeater - but I used DataList - to display the ONE job.

I again used the wizards - then blow out the DataSource setting and item on that page.

We then drop in a gridview for the "many" items (the job items).

I now have this:

```
        <br />
        <div style="border:solid;border-color:black;width:20%">
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                JobSite:
                <asp:Label ID="JobSiteLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobSite") %>' Font-Size="Larger" Font-Bold="true" />
                <br />
                JobDate:
                <asp:Label ID="JobDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("JobDate", "{0:yyyy-MM-dddd}") %>' />
                <br />
                Foreman:
                <asp:Label ID="ForemanLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Foreman") %>' />
                <br />
                Description:
                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <br />
        </div>

        <br />
   
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table borderhide" Width="30%">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox id="txtDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemDescription") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox id="txtQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Qty") %>' TextMode="Number" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Used By">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox id="txtUsedBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UsedBy") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        <div style="float:right">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Item" CssClass="btn" style="margin-top:-20px" />
        </div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:40px"/>


    </div>
```

Ok, and the code to load this up is this:

We load up the main record - just for display, and then the GridView of child items.

```
Dim rstJobItems As New DataTable
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ViewState("JobID") = Session("JobId")
        LoadData()
    Else
        rstJobItems = ViewState("JobItems")
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    DataList1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * from JobSites WHERE ID = " & ViewState("JobID"))
    DataList1.DataBind()

    rstJobItems = MyRst("SELECT * FROM JobItems where Job_ID = " & ViewState("JobID"))

    GridView1.DataSource = rstJobItems
    GridView1.DataBind()
    ViewState("JobItems") = rstJobItems

End Sub
```

Ok, so now on the first page, when we click on a row, we jump to the 2nd page, and we see/have this:

[image]

So we need to wire up the button to add a new row.

That code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAdd.Click

    ' user might have done some edits
    GridToTable()

    ' create a new row
    Dim NewRow As DataRow = rstJobItems.NewRow

    NewRow("Job_id") = ViewState("JobID")
    NewRow("Qty") = 0
    rstJobItems.Rows.Add(NewRow)
    GridView1.DataSource = rstJobItems
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

So, say in above, I click the add row, then you will see this:
(in fact I clicked it two times).

[image]

Ok, so you are free to tab around - edit data in that grid. You can edit/change existing rows, or add a new row and simple tab around and enter data.

So, now lets wire up the Save button. That save button has to allow and deal  with editing rows - and also saving edits - all in ONE shot to the database.

The code for save button is thus this:

```
Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    GridToTable()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM JobItems WHERE ID = 0", conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

            da.Update(rstJobItems)

        End Using
    End Using

    ' data add, and any edit now saved - return to our job site listing page

    Response.Redirect("JobSites.aspx")

End Sub
```

So we send grid to table, and then in ONE database update, send the table back to the database.

Of course after we save, we return back to our first page with the grid now read to edit more.

So, the other routine used in above was sending the Grid (rows) back to the table.

That code is this:

```
Sub GridToTable()

    For Each gRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim OneRow As DataRow = rstJobItems.Rows(gRow.RowIndex)

        OneRow("ItemDescription") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtDesc"), TextBox).Text
        OneRow("Qty") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtQty"), TextBox).Text
        OneRow("UsedBy") = CType(gRow.FindControl("txtUsedBy"), TextBox).Text
    Next

End Sub
```

And of course the cancel button? Well, if you add some rows, or just edit the rows, and hit cancel? Well, we don't save - but just return to the previous page.

eg:

```
Protected Sub cmdCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCancel.Click

    Response.Redirect("JobSites.aspx")

End Sub
```

And last but not least, I have a "general" helper routine that simple returns a data table - and I used it several times in above. That routine kind of gives me a FoxPro or MS-Access like ability to get a data table with great ease (in place of typing that same code over and over).

That routine was this:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData
End Function
```

So the above is quite much start to finish. It is of course quick code, and done rather fast/quick for stack overflow. But it is full of great ideas, and as noted, I let the wizards generate most of the markup. (but then remove the data source from the GV, and also the Data source item that gets created in the page.

So in summary:

I did not write most of that markup - I let the wizards generate most of it.

Note how SMALL and relative simple the code bits were. we broke up this into bite sized parts - thus each routine is not a lot of code.

We ALSO let .net built the sql update (and insert) commands for us. this eliminated BOAT LOADS of parameters, and BOATLOADS of work to wire that up. And it also MUCH better for performance, since ado.net is smart - for rows not changed - it don't send the updates to sql server.

Note also how ONE simple update method of

```
 da.Update(rstJobItems)
```

Handles BOTH edits/updates, an inserts with one command. And we probably could/should drop in a delete row button - and the update would also handle that for us too!!!

So, there is a LOT of great ideas in above, but key concepts are:

Leverage as much as you can the wizards, and built in controls.

Leverage the ability of ado.net to update a table of edits in ONE shot back to the database - and as above shows, SAME single update also works for both inserts and updates at the same time.

Comment: How would a guy go about doing this if the job didnt already exist? What i'm trying to do is turn a paper form into a web based one. The paper version has the job info then a section where we write the items used. I guess what i'm trying to do is make a web based form where we fill in the job details and materials used and hit submit. I suppose I could put rows of input fields for the items used but was trying to get fancy and use an add button :)

Comment: yes, and my example has a add item. Is not that what you looking for? We can move around the add button to anyplace you want. As for layout - that's quite much your choice also.  When you click add item, a new row appears. I mean, how else would this work when you hit add items? The example posted uses and has a add item button - was there something else as to how a add button would work? When you click that button, a new row appears. You are then free to type into that row whatever you want.  How else would you expect this to work? I am now confused here.

Comment: I only put add on 2nd page to add job items. But for the first part? Sure, it would work exact the same as the example in the 2nd page. I left out the add new job button in the first grid - but yes, it would function and work identical to the 2nd page grid example in which click on add wil create a new row.  I kind of thought that this Mr. Obvious was implied here? Just take the 2nd page example of how I added a grid row, and use that on the first page to add a job - same approach. I mean, how much hand holding does one need here???

Comment: I mean, for the first page, we could use add row. However, if the job information was complex, and had a LOT more information? Then sure, we would have a add job button, and if a simple add row to the grid would not suffice, then we would and could create a form to enter the job information, hit save, and then return back to the grid of jobs to then select view, and then you have that 2nd page to display job, and add job items on that page. I mean, how you want this to work is 100% up to you, and you are rather free  as a bird to design this anyway you want.

Comment: And of course, when we jump to that 2nd page, maybe we do that for creating a new job. So on 2nd page we have, we could use that page for BOTH editing existing jobs, and if we hit add job, then that 2nd page top part would have job details that you can edit/fill out first, and then you add job items as per example. So sure, that 2nd page could handle both add a new job, and also to edit existing. So, I did not wire up editing of the top job part - but we certainly could do that. And how that works? Well, it would work identical to the code that saves the grid of job items, but for top datalist

Comment: Top part of the 2nd page could be VAST extended to include much more about the job, and have many more database fields. and you are free to layout that top part job information similar to the paper form you have now. So the bottom job items can also be laid up different, but the concept of one job, and adding items to that job is quite much the meat and potato's here. If you think a post on SO going to give you more? Wow! Anyway, having given this thought? Yes, the 2nd page could be used for both editing existing jobs, and adding a whole new job.  So sure, add more fields to top job info part